# Ubuntu keyring resets automatically when I logout

Tags: gnome-keyring

As written in the Title, when I logout, and login my keyring password is getting reset to my user password after the next reboot.
I tried everything to fix this problem since I installed Ubuntu 12.10
Does anyone know how I can fix this problem, because it makes me crazy.